# when i set the port i got this errorr Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: python, mysql

I use the XAMMP application for MySQL and I want to use the SQL with python so I use pymysql library to connect with MySQL and this the code

```
import pymysql

connection = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="" , port=8080)
```

but I got this error

> OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during
> query')

and this error occurred when I set port 8080 (this port the XAMPP app is connecting to) because if I don’t specify the port then I got another error that can not connect to MySQL and this all the error

> (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 61]
> Connection refused)")

by the way, I searched over google about this error and i found some solutions like changing the max_allowed_packet to 64M but still, this didn’t solve the issue